# Clear css :after declaration with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following css declaration in place:

```
#envelope:after
{
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
}
```

How do I remove it (set it to empty at least) with jQuery at runtime?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't. Psuedo 'elements' are not in the DOM.

Comment: And if your CSS is in a different file, JS can't modify it. JS modifies the HTML only. So when you do change styles, it adds a style attribute to the DOM, not modifying CSS. You could change the ID of your element, and then not have that style for that new ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really "remove" a css rule with jQuery but you can override it for a specific item (or list of items) depending on used selector.

When you are talking about removing it, don't you mean setting a new value instead ?

So if you want to "remove" your z-index, just set it to

```
.css('z-index', 'auto')
```

which is the default value

Same for position

```
.css('position', 'static')
```

Answer (score -1):

Css can't be deleted using any javascript framework

YOu can just remove the css psuedo element from the block element, After performing your work.
Or you can just update the css value to your values.